# javascript/jQuery setInterval/clearInterval

Tags: jquery, plugins, setinterval

i'm using setInterval to check if a p(html paragraph) has a certain text value. if it has it i want to clear interval an continue code flow. i'm using this in a jQuery plugin so if the paragraph has tat text value i want to clear interval and then continue with a callback function.
so i tried something like this:

```
var checkTextValue = setInterval(function(){
                          var textVal = $('p').text();
                          if(textVal == 'expectedValue'){
                              clearInterval(checkTextValue);
                              callback();
                          } 
                     },10);
```

and the callback function it's a simple alert.
My problem is that the alert is called endlessly. How can i write my code to do it right? thanks.

Comment: This is an old issue, but...I can't repro this ( http://jsfiddle.net/gc97D/ ), and I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work.  I think there must be something else going on.  The simplest way to see what's going on is to a) remove your callback, b) console.log the value of checkTextValue /outside/ the function, and c) console.log the value of checkTextValue /inside/ the function.  You'll probably want to increase the timer to something larger than 10, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use setTimeout instead of setInterval.

Something like:

```
var checkTextValue = setTimeout(function() {
    var textVal = $('p').text();
    if (textVal == 'expectedValue'){
        callback();
    } else {
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
    }
},10);
```

Comment: In general, I agree that this is a better approach. But doesn't really answer the question of why that code doesn't work.

Comment: ok, this works but now the problem is that in firefox i still get that animation and loading bar like the page is loading and the message transferring data...

Comment: That should be unrelated.  setTimeout has to do with internal method calls, while the Firefox loading indicator has to do with external HTTP requests.